# Is it possible to write two disjoint Datasets to data sync using foreachBatch in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm trying to write the data from single source to multiple DataSinks (Mongo and Postgres DBs).
Incoming data

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "topic1")
        .load();

Dataset<Row> personalDetails = df.selectExpr("name", "id", "age");


personalDetails.writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .foreachBatch((dataframe, bachId) -> {
            dataframe.write().format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost/employee")
                    .option("database", "employee")
                    .option("collection", "PI").save();
    }).start();

Dataset<Row> salDetails = df.selectExpr("basicSal", "bonus");
salDetails.writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .foreachBatch((dataframe, bachId) -> {
            dataframe.write().format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost/employee")
                    .option("database", "employee")
                    .option("collection", "SAL").save();
    }).start();
```

Problem with this is, I can see the Spark is opening the two Streams and reading the same events twice.
Is it possible to read once and apply different transformations and write to different collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cache the DataFrame.
See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch):

> Write to multiple locations - If you want to write the output of a streaming query to multiple locations, then you can simply write the output DataFrame/Dataset multiple times. However, each attempt to write can cause the output data to be recomputed (including possible re-reading of the input data). To avoid recomputations, you should cache the output DataFrame/Dataset, write it to multiple locations, and then uncache it.

And their example:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```

You can put all of your code in one `foreachBatch` and write the dataframe to your 2 sinks. You can do that by caching the dataframe, and performing the `selectExpr` on this cached dataframe, and saving it.

*As a side note* - please notice that in any case, if you wanted "all or nothing"(i.e. you don't want a situation where you wrote to mongo and not to postgres), you must use only one `foreachBatch`, because otherwise (if you have 2 `foreachBatch`, as in your question) you have 2 independent batches - one might fail when the other one succeeded, for the same data.

Comment: The foreachBatch works well in case when you just want to write stream without additional processing in between tow location syncs.

Comment: The `foreachBatch` works well in case when you just want to write stream without additional processing in between tow location syncs. Looking at the note [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) 
"Apply additional DataFrame operations - Many DataFrame and Dataset operations are not supported in streaming DataFrames"

Comment: I'm not sure why you claim that - did you try my proposed solution? foreachBatch does allow you to perform operations on the batchDf, e.g. creating a new DataFrame by running `sql` on the batchDf.

Comment: Also please read the rest of the sentence from the link - "Using foreachBatch, you can apply some of these operations on each micro-batch output".

Comment: I'm already using foreachBatch to write same data to multiple data sinks. As stated in question I needed write two different(disjoint) Datasets to data sink. And inside foreachBatch it's not possible to apply all transformations which are defined on Dataset

Comment: But you can use `df.selectExpr(X, Y)` inside the foreachBatch. And then you get a DataFrame which you can write to wherever you need. And in another line you can again use `df.selectExpr(X, Z)` to create another DataFrame which you can write. I've even tested it locally and it works, foreachBatch does support it. I've explained this solution in my answer above. It's working. So my question is - did you try it? did you encounter any issue with it?

Comment: When I tried last time with spark 3.0.0, I had encountered an issue may be I did something wrong. But I tried yesterday after your comment.. it worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve this issue using **Spark 3.1.1** using **Structured Streaming Table API**.

> Since Spark 3.1, you can also use DataStreamReader.table() to read tables as streaming DataFrames and use DataStreamWriter.toTable() to write streaming DataFrames as tables:

```
    // Stream to myTable
    df.writeStream()
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/test")
      .toTable("myTable");
    // Stream from myTable
    Dataset<Row> tableDf = spark.readStream()
                                .table("myTable");
```

Refer: [Spark 3.1 Table API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-table-apis)

With this I could solve the problem of multiple reads from source "kafka". With this it'll  create only one Kafka consumer and stream data to Table. From there it will use multiple streams to read from table and apply additional transformations on top of table dataset.
So the complete example looks as follows:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "topic1")
        .load();

// Stream to myTable
df.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", "c:/temp/test").toTable("myTable");

// Stream from myTable
Dataset<Row> tableDf = spark.readStream().table("myTable");

Dataset<Row> personalDetails = tableDf.selectExpr("name", "id", "age");


personalDetails.writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .foreachBatch((dataframe, bachId) -> {
            dataframe.write().format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost/employee")
                    .option("database", "employee")
                    .option("collection", "PI").save();
    }).start();

Dataset<Row> salDetails = tableDf.selectExpr("basicSal", "bonus");
salDetails.writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .foreachBatch((dataframe, bachId) -> {
            dataframe.write().format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("uri", "mongodb://localhost/employee")
                    .option("database", "employee")
                    .option("collection", "SAL").save();
    }).start();
```