# Does spark.sql.adaptive.enabled work for Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I work with Apache Spark Structured Streaming. Structured Streaming is a scalable and fault-tolerant stream processing engine built on the Spark SQL engine. Since It builds on the Spark SQL engine, does it mean spark.sql.adaptive.enabled works for Spark Structured Streaming?

Answer (score 2):

It's disabled in Spark code - See in [StreamExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L285):

```
// Adaptive execution can change num shuffle partitions, disallow
sparkSessionForStream.conf.set(SQLConf.ADAPTIVE_EXECUTION_ENABLED.key, "false")
```

The reason for that is because it might cause issues when having state on the stream (more details in the ticket that added this restriction - [SPARK-19873](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19873) ).

If you still want to enable it for the Spark Structured Streaming (e.g. if you are sure that it won't cause any harm in your use case), you can do that inside the `foreachBatch` method,  by setting `batchDF.sparkSession.conf.set(SQLConf.ADAPTIVE_EXECUTION_ENABLED.key, "true")` - this will override the Spark code which disabled it.

Comment: Hello, would you have an example how it would look like within the actual writeSteam code?

For example would it look something like this?

df = (transformedSourceDF.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", chkpoint)
  .foreachBatch(sparkSession.conf.set(SQLConf.ADAPTIVE_EXECUTION_ENABLED.key, "true"))
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .start(saveLoc, outputMode="append")

Thank you

Comment: Hi, this isn't how the `foreachBatch` method is used nor its purpose - in my case I used it anyway. Please read about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch). Also make sure you understand the cases where enabling AQE in there could be incorrect, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Hi yishaiz, I understand. Basically we are using batch streaming to move files that have been dropped and are being loaded as batches vs traditional streaming (always on). 

I am new to write and readStream so was wondering how to actually add that spark config to the foreachBatch. Since I was not able to find any examples that you listed above that is why I was hoping for some kind of syntax on how to enable it inside for eachBatch. Or would this be a spark config that is applied on a cluster?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For how to use `foreachBatch` itself you can find many examples, one of them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203175/3883957). Then, in this example, you can add the `batchDF.sparkSession.conf.set(SQLConf.ADAPTIVE_EXECUTION_ENABLED.key, "true") ` line as the first line inside the `foreachBatch` function (just above the `batchDF.persist()` line)

Comment: Hi @yishaiz,

Thank you for all the info. I was able to add that in, but (and this might not be related to this) I see that in the stage that pulls the records in the SQLConf.ADAPTIVE_EXECUTION_ENABLED.key is enabled, but it still shows spark.sql.adaptive.enabled and spark.sql.cbo.enabled as false. Is that normal? I guess I was assuming that by setting the ADAPTIVE spark config above to true I would see spark.sql.adaptive.enabled be set to true, but it is set to false.

In any case thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get, where do you see it set to false? In any case, ultimately the way to verify it's indeed working is to see the affect in the DAG or in the debug logs

Answer (score 0):

No. Stated in this doc https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/aqe.html. Non-streaming not supported, does not apply for AQE.

Think of statefulness, small datasets ideally. Many restrictions in Spark Structured Streaming.